# BottlePy, SQLite3 - Storage of request form to database - KeyError 0

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to get user inputs from a `HTML` form, and store them into a `SQlite3` database.

HTML form has 1 radio button set (with 4 choices), and 7 text inputs. It looks like this (without all the formatting) :

```
<input type="radio" name="ProducteurType" value="Prod" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="ProducteurType" value="Coll"> 
<input type="radio" name="ProducteurType" value="Traitement">
<input type="radio" name="ProducteurType" value="Autre">

<input type="text" name="ProducteurSIRET">
<input type="text" name="ProducteurNOM">
<input type="text" name="ProducteurAdresse">
<input type="text" name="ProducteurTel">
<input type="text" name="ProducteurFax">
<input type="text" name="ProducteurCourriel">
<input type="text" name="ProducteurContact">
```

I use the following code to store these inputs into a database :

```
@post('/ajoutClient')
def ajoutClient():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/bsd.db')
    create_if_need = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Clients (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                            ProducteurType TEXT,
                                            ProducteurSIRET TEXT,
                                            ProducteurNOM TEXT,
                                            ProducteurAdresse TEXT,
                                            ProducteurTel TEXT,
                                            ProducteurFax TEXT,
                                            ProducteurCourriel TEXT,
                                            ProducteurContact TEXT)"""
    conn.execute(create_if_need)
    rf = request.forms
    insert_client_query = """
    INSERT INTO 
        Clients(ProducteurType,ProducteurSIRET,ProducteurNOM,ProducteurAdresse,ProducteurTel,ProducteurFax,ProducteurCourriel,ProducteurContact) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"""
    conn.execute(insert_client_query,rf)
    conn.commit
```

I get the following error :

> ```
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1826, in __getitem__
>     def __getitem__(self, key): return self.dict[key][-1]
> KeyError: 0
> ```

I understand that "KeyError 0" means that, somehow, I am giving too much or not enough fields to the database.

I have filled all fields in the form, so there is no empty value.
I have checked the number of fields : there are 8 of them, in the form and in the database.
I have checked the field names : they are identical.

Did I do wrong with the "id" primary key ?
Is HTML "radio" input not compatible with database insertion, or should I store it as 4 booleans (one would be true, the three others beeing false) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I badly used the request.forms dictionnary. This code works :

```
rf = request.forms
conn.execute('INSERT INTO Clients values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [\
    rf['ProducteurType'],\
    rf['ProducteurSIRET'],\
    rf['ProducteurNOM'],\
    rf['ProducteurAdresse'],\
    rf['ProducteurTel'],\
    rf['ProducteurFax'],\
    rf['ProducteurCourriel'],\
    rf['ProducteurContact'] ])
conn.commit
```